# JAVA Hibernate merge is updating and not merging

Tags: java, hibernate

When I use merge I expect that hibernate will copy not null values to a persisted entity and update the database. So in the bellow use-case, I expect that the merge will keep `lastName` with the value `Last_0` and change `firstName` to the value  `First_1`.

but actually, hibernate is just updating, meaning that `lastName` become null after the code execute

```
    @Transactional
    public void create()  {
        SomeEntity create = new SomeEntity();
        create.setFirstName("First_0");
        create.setLastName("Last_0");
        this.getSession().save(create);
        //now in the database id:1, firstName:First_0, lastName:Last_0
   }


   @Transactional
    public void merge()  {
        SomeEntity merge = new SomeEntity();
        merge.setId(1);
        merge.setFirstName("First_1");
        this.getSession().merge(merge);
         // now in the database id:1, firstName:First_1, lastName:null
    }
    create();
    merge();
```

I expect `lastName` to be with the value of `Last_0` since it is merging. but it is null.

Thanks

Comment: I question whether the first name were really still `First_0` after the call to `merge()`.

Comment: firstName:First_1, sorry, I changed the value. `id:1, firstName:First_1, lastName:null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about how Hibernate's `merge()` is implemented in practice.  `merge()` is implemented under the hood in this case via a SQL `UPDATE`, meaning something like the following:

```
UPDATE some_entity
SET
    firstName = 'First_1',
    lastName = NULL
WHERE
    id = 1;
```

That is, it will overwrite all the field values with whatever your detached entity happens to have.  Note that if no record with this primary key `id=1` existed, then Hibernate would have done an `INSERT`, not an update.

If you wanted to start off with the original values for the entity, then you should have used a get:

```
SomeEntity merge = (SomeEntity) this.getSession().get(SomeEntity.class, 1);
merge.setFirstName("First_1");
this.getSession().merge(merge);
```

Now the original values will "stick," except for the first name, which was overwritten to something else.

Comment: So merge is just an update? I don't get it. the java code you submitted is the same as `saveOrUpdate`. as far as I understand the entire point of a merge is to take a detached object and mege it with the database values where the field value is not null. whats the point?

Comment: `merge` will do an _insert_ if the entity does not even exist, this is the difference AFAIK.

Comment: So you can say that `merge(T entity)` can be renamed to `update(T entity)`? there is no real merge? thanks

Comment: Hibernate's merge concept is that it will update an entity which is already there, or insert a new record if not already there, this is all there is to the concept.

Comment: Thank you, what is the best way to accomplish what my expected scenario? this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-maps ?

Comment: This is a completely different `merge()` function, not related to your original question.  I suggest opening a new question if you need this follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want hibernate to only save part of fields and not all of them
use `@DynamicUpdate`

Example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-dynamicupdate

As posted inside:

> Actually, when we use @DynamicUpdate on an entity, Hibernate does not use the cached SQL statement for the update. Instead, it will generate a SQL statement each time we update the entity. This generated SQL includes only the changed columns.

Comment: Thank you but this is not the case. in order to use `@DynamicUpdate` you need to fetch from the database, set values and save. I am getting my object from the client. totally detached and i try to merge it with the database row. I thought that the merge takes a detached object and fetch from the database and update each value which is not null.